# jquery sortable and droppable - cannot append the drop item?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to append the dropped item into the targeted droppable box from the sortable list, but I cannot append the dropped item into the specific element.

My jquery,

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    update: function(){
    // php update.
    }
}).disableSelection();


$( ".droppable" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {

        var targetElem = $(this).attr("id");

        $( this )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
            .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped! inside " + targetElem );

            alert(targetElem);

        var container = $( this ).find( "ul.dropped-items" ).css({border:"blue solid 1px"});

        container.append(ui.draggable.clone());

        ui.draggable.remove();

    }
});
```

The dropped item should be appended into this element,

```
<ul class="dropped-items">
</ul>
```

But it just not happening. What have I missed and how can I make it work?

[jsfiddle test page](http://jsfiddle.net/sAEar/).

Comment: Works fine for me. There's an `li` appended to the `ul`. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Still no luck from my side. Yes I want `li appended to the ul`. thanks.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Works for me too. I think you may simply be seeing wrong due to position being absolute.

Comment: It is appended. Maybe you're talking about styling issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could removing the absolute position styling on the element:

**Javascript**

```
...
container.append(ui.draggable.clone().css({position: 'relative', left: 0, top: 0, width: 'auto', height: 'auto'}));
...
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sAEar/6/)**

Or, add the styling in to do the same:

**CSS**

```css
.dropped-items li {
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sAEar/8/)**

Comment: why there is `absolute position styling on the element`? I didn't set it in my css at all...