# Sortable and Droppable: CSS preventing jquery-ui sortable to drag around the dropped items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-ui-sortable

After getting the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870942/jquery-sortable-and-droppable-cannot-append-the-drop-item), I came across another problem - how can I be able to drag the dropped items again?

I have set the css of the dropped items to,

```
.dropped-items li {
        position: relative !important;
        top: 0 !important;
        left: 0 !important;
        width: 120px !important;
        height: auto !important;
        border: 1px solid black !important;
    }
```

But this will prevent `jquery-ui sortable` to drag around the dropped items.

What can I do?

[jsfiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAEar/10/).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you just use two connected sortable lists? http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: thanks. I have another list of items to drop into the two or more albums - that is the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result you want by not using the css you specified and instead "overwriting" the inline-styles set by jQuery just after the element is appended:

```
container.children().last().css({ position: 'relative', top: '', left: '' });
```

Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAEar/11/)